# Starting AVAssetExportSession in the Background

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

My app does some processing and at some point it needs to call an AVAssetExportSession.

If the session has already started and then I background the app, everything completes normally. However, if I background the app before calling `exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler`. I get this error:

`AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x1e550db0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12985), NSUnderlyingError=0x1e574910 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (OSStatus error -12985.)", NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}`

Is it possible to start an AVAssetExportSession in the background?

Comment: I can't get it to run in the background at all. Even if the session is started before going into the background, it gets interrupted immediately. Are you using the  _backgroundTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{... to make it run in the background?

Comment: @eddy Yes I am using something like that

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually is not possible due to the fact that you can't start a new thread in the background. If you want to do a lot of things in the background you'll have to start them all asynchronously right before the app backgrounds.

Answer (score 4):

You can start `AVAssetExportSession` in background. The only limitations in `AVFoundation` to performing work in the background, are using `AVVideoCompositions` or `AVMutableVideoCompositions`. `AVVideoCompositions` are using the GPU, and the GPU cannot be used in the background.

Comment: I am failing to export audio in the background do you have a sample or a link ?

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution which works for audio, I have not tried video

If you update your "Background Modes" setting in the capabilities of the project to include Audio. It will allow the export.

This is intended for playing music in the background.

Comment: I *think* iOS 8 might even now allow GPU processing to happen in the background too.

Comment: This works on IOS 7 as well as 8, I have not tested on prior versions

Comment: It definitely didn't when I opened this question ;) What a pain it was!

Comment: I am seeing inconsistent behavior. It seems like I can start/finish export sessions in the background. But export fails if the app is backgrounded in the middle of the exportSession.

Comment: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11847 "Operation Interrupted" UserInfo=0x1974ff10 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Stop other operations and try again., NSUnderlyingError=0x1936a5d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -16101.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Interrupted}

Comment: Alfie perhaps open a new question with more of your code. I have not witnessed your error.