# AVAssetExportSession working in background

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avassetexportsession

I tried to manage AVAssetExportSession working when app in background. I have iOS 6 device and testing it there. So i m making audio mix and trying to export audio. When app is in foreground i m making all OK, but if i m going to background i m getting AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed and have to create it from beginning. So, is it ever possible to make audio mixing work in background?

I m trying to make [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: ] in NSOperationQueue or getting global queue - but the results is the same - it stops when app going in background and sending failed afterwards.

Does anyone have an example with AVAssetExportSession working in background?

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution which works for audio, I have not tried video

If you update your "Background Modes" setting in the capabilities of the project to include Audio. It will allow the export.

This is intended for playing music in the background.

---- Edit ---

This also works for video

[image]

Comment: See this q/a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846653/starting-avassetexportsession-in-the-background

Comment: I had seen that but do not agree that it is not possible since I use it.

Comment: Yeah I was just adding that for future reference, further down on that page there's discussion of it working after iOS7...

Comment: @Ryan Heitner What's the version of the iOS.

Comment: 7.1 Deployment Target Target 8.1 SDK

Comment: @RyanHeitner I added "App plays audio in background" so it didn t do the trick. Did i misunderstand your "includes audio" background mode?

Comment: I have added a pic to clarify. Hope it helps, I do not understand why it isn't a fix all. The background fetch in the pic is specific to my app.